# Node JS Slow upload with Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, multer

I'm working on a project with an instance (my test server) with Docker.

I have actually a client (front of upload app) and an api with Node JS and multer storage and Google Cloud Storage.

My Database is a ReplicaSet of 3 containers MongoDB (1 primary and 2 secondary).

The problem is during the upload, the process is very long (POST 17sec).

My strategy is to store the informations of the file (png, pdf, jpeg...) in my mongoDB Database, and store the file on a filesystem mounted to my api container.
If the file is an image, then we resize it to a thumbmail and store it in the filesystem, update the document path in mongodb, upload to Google Cloud Storage the file (original size) and delete it to the local.

But all of this process with my code is very long.

```
// Enable Storage
const gcs = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: 'myprojectid',
    keyFilename: 'mykeyfilename',
});

// environments Variables
let clientUrl;
let smtpTransport;
let bucket;


 bucket = gcs.bucket('mybucket');

 module.exports = {

    async create(req, res) {
        const upload = multer({
            storage: multer.diskStorage({
                destination: (req, file, callback) => {
                    const client = JSON.parse(req.body.client);
                    const companyName = client.company_name;
                    const type = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
                    const path = `./uploads/${companyName}/${type}`;
                    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
                    callback(null, path);
                },
                filename: (req, file, callback) => {
                    // originalname is the uploaded file's name with extn
                    callback(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
                },
            }),
            limits: {
                fileSize: 500000000, // 500mb max
            },
        }).array('document');

        try {
            await upload(req, res, async () => {
                let addedBy;
                const docs = [];

                const userTypeJwt = extractTypeUserJwt(req);

                if (userTypeJwt === 'admins') {
                    addedBy = 'admin';
                } else {
                    addedBy = 'client';
                }

                const client = JSON.parse(req.body.client);

                req.files.forEach(async (file) => {
                    try {
                        const doc = await Document.create({
                            filename: file.originalname,
                            client: {
                                client_id: client._id,
                                company_name: client.company_name,
                                firstname: client.firstname,
                                lastname: client.lastname,
                                email: client.email,
                            },
                            added_by: addedBy,
                            mimetype: file.mimetype,
                            path: file.path,
                            size: file.size,
                        });
                        docs.push(doc);

                        /**
                         * Resizing de l'image originel
                         *
                         * Puis update path du document dans la base de donnée
                         */
                        const resizedPath = await imgProc(file, client.company_name);
                        await doc.update({
                            path: resizedPath,
                        });

                        /**
                         * Vérification image ?
                         *
                         * Si oui, upload de l'image originel sur le google cloud storage
                         *
                         * Suppression du fichier origine sur le local
                         */
                        if (file.mimetype.split('/')[0] === 'image') {
                            await bucket.upload(file.path);
                            console.log('File uploaded to Google cloud Storage');
                            await fs.unlink(file.path);
                            console.log('File deleted from local');
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });

                if (addedBy === 'client') {
                    const mailOptions = {
                        to: config.contact_email,
                        from: config.contact_email,
                        subject: `${client.company_name} a uploadé dans son Espace`,
                        template: 'client_upload',
                        context: {
                            company_name: client.company_name,
                            docs,
                        },
                    };

                    try {
                        await smtpTransport.use('compile', mailerhbs({
                            viewPath: 'templates/emails',
                            extName: '.hbs',
                        }));
                        await smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
                        console.log('Send mail to mysmail@mail.com...');
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }

                res.json({ success: true, message: 'Document(s) successfuly uploaded.' });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    },
```